# TypeError: fetch failed in Docker

Tags: node.js, docker, microsoft-graph-api, nestjs, typeerror

I am using the `MS Graph API` in a `NodeJS` application to interact with files in OneDrive using the `microsoft-graph-client` library. Everything functions correctly in the local build, but when I run the application in Docker, I encounter an error while attempting to retrieve a file from OneDrive, even though the `Batch` requests operates normally.

**Request that triggers the error:**

```
const response = await this.client
      .api('users/{userID}/drive/root:/myapp/' + filename + '.pptx:/content')
      .get();
```

**Error**

```
TypeError: fetch failed
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11372:11)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  statusCode: -1,
  code: 'TypeError',
  requestId: null,
  date: 2023-11-13T15:50:09.758Z,
  body: 'TypeError: fetch failed',
  headers: undefined
}
```

The error occurs when I run the application in Docker. How can I resolve it?